# Zbar importing Library issues

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-file, zbar

I am having trouble importing the zbar library properly.

I am following this guide:

https://github.com/DushyanthMaguluru/ZBarScanner

The guide says:

Download this project and add it as a library project to your existing Android app

I downloaded this project and created a library from ZbarScannerLibary folder. I then set in the properties of my project this liabry to be used.

I then continued the guide, when I started to code the main activity I received errors that variables and imports cannot be resolved.

[image]

What am I doing wrong and how can I get the imports to be resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a variable in your `Activity`:

```
public static final int ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 0;
public static final int ZBAR_OR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 1;

//etc
```

These are just used for handling activity result. In the short run, you can also comment out the `onActivityResult` method to test the barcode is working. You then open the barcode with:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

Finally, be sure to read up on [`startActivityForResult`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29), since it is a very important topic when developing a multi-activity app.